# How to get residuals between real values and values of locpoly curve in R?

Tags: r, function

I have a problem while trying to get residuals between real values (dots) ant curve got after applying locpoly function.

this is my code and graph which I get

```
>plot(one,two)
>bw=dpill(one, two)
>local.linear=locpoly(one, two, bandwidth = bw, degree = 1)
>lines(local.linear$x, local.linear$y, type="l")
```

[image]